# camel-cmis Filenet Storing metadata and Document

Tags: apache-camel, metadata, opencmis, filenet-p8

Below is my metadata Document class and property definition I created.

DocClassDisplayName - ClassSymbolicName

**CustomMeta  -  doc_CustomMeta**

PropDisplayname - PropSymbolicName - Datatype

```
SINo - prp_SINo - String(64)
VersionNo - prp_VersionNo - String(64)
User - prp_User - String(64)
Agency - prp_Agency - String(64)
```

Below is my camel route to store document

```
from("activemq:queue:STORE_DOCUMENT_QUEUE")
.process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(PropertyIds.CONTENT_STREAM_MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf; charset=UTF-8");
        exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(PropertyIds.NAME, exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME));
        exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put(CamelCMISConstants.CMIS_FOLDER_PATH, "/TEST");
    }
})
.to("cmis://${header.cmisUrl}");
```

I'm stuck with setting above metadata to camel exchange in order to store metadata along with storing document.

I tried setting one metadata to camel exchange like the example below but it didn't work.

```
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put("cmis:xyz_SINo,"001");
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put("cmis:xyz_VersionNo,"0001");
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put("cmis:xyz_User,"TestUser");
exchange.getIn().getHeaders().put("cmis:xyz_Agency,"TestAgency");
```

Can anybody show me a way using camel-cmis in order to achieve what I need?